# list item not updating till refresh the page in Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jsom

I have javascript to update the item title which loads while displaying the form(display form), the item is updating fine but till I refresh the page only, not while loading the view item

**Here is the written code**

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Test_Versioning');

var oListItem = oList.getItemById(itemID);
oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My Updated Title New1');
oListItem.set_item('Editor', userid);
oListItem.update();
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('Item updated!');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to using this fuction, all your code will be execute after loading

< !--#_

AddPostRenderCallback(ctx, function(){
   });

_#-- >

sorry for my last response, i was not read good

Comment: i changed the response, i wasn't read good, i m sorry